# Ethernet interface is down after GNOME crash

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, 22.04, ethernet

I was doing some random, network intensive thing (apt-getting) on my Ubuntu 22.04 box today when I abruptly went from GNOME to a black screen. After booting up, I had a CLI only - no GNOME. All my files were OK.

After hours of fiddling, I still have no GNOME, and ip, ifconfig, and nmcli are all in agreement that my ethernet interface is down. `sudo lshw -c network` says my ethernet is DISABLED.

My hardware is an ethernet adapter connecting through USB. I have proven that the hardware works.

Question 1: What happened?
Question 2: What can I do about this?

`sudo ip link set <device> on` turns it on, but after a reboot it's off again.

Comment: Do a `$ lsblk -ape7` and check the `RO` column, all devices should be "0" (i.e. in Read/Write mode, if not check which ones you need to be RW, attempt 'fsck' from `recovery mode`). Then try `apt update && apt upgrade` and see what happens; any errors? add the text shown to your question above.

Comment: lsblk -ape7 says RO is zero everywhere.

Comment: One more try... 1) google "recovery mode", enable it. 2) in the menu do `fsck`, 3) and `enable network` (your 'up link on' command might be required) . 4) and then `apt update && apt upgrade` from the root shell prompt 5) See what happens; any errors? add the text shown to your question above

Comment: This is to ensure that there isn't any outstanding updates or missing configuration; which might be the cause for your problem; you were in the process of doing system updates as the black screen appeared. Also; network being down should not make 'GNOME' not start.